# How to get editor data without any special character in php

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

I am working with php and i am trying to get data from "Editor" ( like Tinymyc),But
right now i am getting special characters like `"<strong> ,<p>"` etc..i just want to get simple data
without any special characters,how can i do this ?I tried with following code

```
$data=$_POST['editor'];
```

Comment: You can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php to strip those "special characters"

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try - if your code is correct this should work.

```
$data = strip_tags($_POST['editor']);
```